# marginpar always on left side

Tags: marginpar

[image]In my document, `marginpar` always needs to be place in left side of the page, and I need to place chapter number and some element in that margin par width, for this I've tried with the below tags:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter

\usepackage[a4,center,cam,info,]{crop}

\setlength{\paperheight}{9truein}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{7truein}%

\setlength\textwidth{30pc}
\setlength\textheight{40pc}

\setlength\marginparwidth{48\p@}%

\setlength\oddsidemargin{5pc}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}    % subtract out the 1 inch driver margin
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{\marginparwidth}%
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{\marginparsep}%
\setlength\@tempdima{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima{-5pc}
\setlength\evensidemargin{\@tempdima}
\addtolength\evensidemargin{-1in}

\@mparswitchfalse%
\reversemarginpar
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Test

\clearpage

Trial

\end{document}
```

And the output came as `marginpar` at right side only, how can I change this into leftside for all pages? Please suggest...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the commands in a wrong order. Changing

```
\@mparswitchfalse%
\reversemarginpar
```

into

```
\reversemarginpar
\@mparswitchfalse%
```

ensures that the correct margin is not changed anymore.

Comment: @TeXniician Thanks for your quick suggestion, but still the page setup looks like same. Please refer the screenshot for clarification...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Have you actually used a `\marginpar`? You will see that the content is added on the left side!

Comment: oops....sorry, yes, it's working fine, is there any possible to move the marginpar frame also to left side? Sorry for the confusion....

Comment: @MadyYuvi I have no idea about the showframe package…