# Set left side marginnote in Latex in documentclass book

Tags: marginnote

I am writting a book and i want to only left side marginnote in all pages

like this: [image]
but doesn't work perfectly.
I will appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,textsize=scriptsize]{todonotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
asdkf asd;faks fd sdflas dfl
\reversemarginpar
\marginnote{This is a margin note using the geometry package, set at 5cm 
vertical offset to the first line it is typeset.}[3cm]
\newpage
\reversemarginpar
\marginnote{This is a margin note using the geometry package, set at 5cm 
vertical offset to the first line it is typeset.}[3cm]
\newpage
\reversemarginpar
\marginnote{This is a margin note using the geometry package, set at 5cm 
vertical offset to the first line it is typeset.
\colorbox{red}{asdf}
}[3cm]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... I believe this was not as `marginnote`, it is related to stub column in left side only

Comment: Hope this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466512/marginpar-always-on-left-side may helps you...

Comment: Thank you so much MadyYuvi

Comment: Based on you `comment`, I've voted this question as `closed`, FYI...