# Book template similar to Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning

Tags: templates, books, book-design

Bishop's PRML is a well known book and extremely beautiful in my view. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a book template to give a similar look. A sample chapter is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bishop-PRML-sample.pdf).

I haven't found any templates that do all these (e.g. [Tufte-book](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex)); in particular the different figure caption widths and layouts aren't elsewhere.

The particular aspects that appeal to me are:

- use of colours across captions, headings, and so on
- quite a few figure layouts: full width; within text column; partial width (e.g. Fig 8.9, 8.10, 8.21 for fullwidth)
- Cross references to sections, excerises, in the margins
- Various fonts
- Section heading underlines & chapter first page

Here's just one page (hopefully fair use) to make the point:

[image]

Edit: link to Tufte book style

Comment: You don't need a full width figure so much as putting the caption number (not the entire caption) into the marginpar area (custom \caption).  The only odd thing is why the red "Section 8.2" is in the middle of subsection 8.3.1.  Is it a link?

Comment: That's a cross-reference to the section; presumably a form of cleverref overload of \sidenote or something!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not a comlete solution, but it should help get you started.  BTW, I stole the page setup from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466512/marginpar-always-on-left-side).  Note that you can't use `\marginpar` inisde a float, but you can simply overlap the margin.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\evensidemargin}
\reversemarginpar
\csname @mparswitchfalse\endcsname

\newsavebox{\threepartbox}

\newenvironment{threepartfigure}[2][\empty]{% #1 = short caption (optional), #2 = caption (with \label)
  \long\def\longcap{#2}%
  \def\shortcap{#1}%
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \let\shortcap=\longcap
  \fi
  \begin{lrbox}{\threepartbox}}% must be an \hbox, not a \vbox
{\end{lrbox}%
  \refstepcounter{figure}%
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\string\numberline{\thefigure}\shortcap}%
  \leavevmode\llap{\textcolor{red}{\figurename~\thefigure}\hspace{\marginparsep}}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\threepartbox-\columnsep}{\small\bfseries\sffamily\longcap}%
  \hfill\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{\usebox\threepartbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{threepartfigure}{\blindtext}
    \rule{2in}{1in}
  \end{threepartfigure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext\marginpar{marginpar test}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]